# How to push footer to the bottom without using position absolute?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, footer

I have created a search page to search for images using an API. The problem is that when first loading the page, there is not enough content to have the footer positioned where it should be.

I can't use position absolute, as all of the internet seems to suggest, because if I do, when I search for images and the gallery is dynamically created and loaded, the footer will stick on top of it, and not end up at the bottom.

I also read something about adding a margin or anyway a fixed blank space between the element with my search bar and my footer. Problem there is that when I load the gallery, I would end up with a big blank space between the end of it and my footer, than I don't want.

So the only thing I can think of is that I would have to create an empty element to fill that gap, which would then be toggled away when loading the gallery. But I wanted to know if there is a more simple and elegant solution to fix the issue and push the footer to the bottom.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add code Here HTML & CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: fixed`;

```css
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sticky Footer</h2>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page without using position absolute.</p>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That will do the job :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried position fixed now, but then when I load the gallery, the footer will remain visible all the time, which I don't want either :/ I want it at the bottom of the browser window and/or content. Whichever is lower

Comment: @Marica please try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/523euaph/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `height: calc()` for a dynamic height. If you do not want a scrollbar then make the footer height equal to the `calc(100% - __px)` height.

The css calc() property will recalculate the height if the content changes or the browser view changes.

The footer is at the bottom of the browser view (if content is not long) or at the end of the content (if content is longer then view).

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.page-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.not-footer {
  min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  background: #fcc;
}
.footer {
  height: 60px;
  background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">

  <div class="not-footer">
    content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>

</div>
```